# How can I solve the import error in Python running on Mac?

Tags: python

It's throwing error for this. I am working on Python to query from Snowflake and it's on a MAC OS.

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
from config import config

conn =sf.connect(user=config.username,password=config.password,account=config.account)
```

Error is following.

```
"/Users/xxxxxx/Snowflake Project/bin/python" "/Users/xxxxxx/PycharmProjects/Snowflake Project/Snowflake_selectrecord.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/PycharmProjects/Snowflake Project/Snowflake_selectrecord.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'config' (/Users/xxxxxx/PycharmProjects/Snowflake Project/config.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am new to Python and not able to get away with the error. I searched forums and didn't get a reply that solved my error.

Config.py:

```
username='xxxxx'
password=''
account='xxxxxxxedo.us-east-1'
warehouse= 'reporting_wh'
database='reporting_nonprod'
```

Comment: Is there a `config` inside of `config.py`?

Comment: Yes this is inside config - username='XXXXX'
password=''
account='xxxxxx.us-east-1'
warehouse= 'reporting_wh'
database='reporting_nonprod'

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments. Add it to the question itself.

Comment: Updated config.py in question

Comment: Your `config.py` does not contain a name `config`. You can import all the other existing names.

Comment: How can I import everything in Config.py as a single import? @KlausD.

Comment: Issue is solved by giving just "import config" instead of 'from config import config'